# "the scars were thrown into relief by the candlelight" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Kneeling man almost fell over in his haste to obey. His face was pockmarked; **the scars were thrown into relief by the candlelight**. He remained a little stooped when standing, as though halfway through a bow, and he darted terrified looks up at Harry's face.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I don't quite understand what it means by "**the scars were thrown into relief by the candlelight**". Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bring-throw-something-into-relief

Comment: @userr2684291 Oh I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that [it was made very obvious or very visible](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bring-throw-something-into-relief). I believe this actually comes from ***relief*** as [a sort of sculpture or other art form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief), which is the same sense of *relief* as in *relief map*, a map that shows differences in height above sea level in some way. Essentially, it's saying that the scar was **made to stand out**, figuratively and perhaps literally, looking more three-dimensional than it usually does.